# Java Undo Managaer, Why one character at a time

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I've made a undo manager, my problem is that it only undoes one character at a time, if you enter more than one character it undoes only the last, I want it to undo the next also if you press undo again and so on.

```
try {
    undoManager.undo();

} catch (CannotUndoException ex) {

}

textArea.getDocument().addUndoableEditListener(new UndoableEditListener() {

    @Override
    public void undoableEditHappened(UndoableEditEvent e) {
        undoManager.addEdit(e.getEdit());

    }
});
```

Comment: The `UndoManager` _is an_ `UndoableEditListener`. As [`the documentation`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/undo/UndoManager.html) states - `tf.getDocument().addUndoableEditListener(undoManager);`.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Compound Undo Manager](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/27/compound-undo-manager/). It attempts to undo groups of text that have been typed together at the same time.